# ImagePullBackOff unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

I have gone through all the motions and I have what appears to be a common problem. Unfortunately, all of the solutions I've tried from github and SO have yet to work. Here's the error:

```
Warning  Failed     4m (x4 over 5m)    kubelet, aks-agentpool-97052351-0  Failed to pull image "ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required]
```

-- created the service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac 
  --scopes /subscriptions/11870e73-bdb2-47b0-bf27-25d24c41ae24/resourcegroups/USS-MicroService-Test/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/UssMicroServiceRegistry
  --role Reader 
  --name kimage-reader
```

-- created the secret for Kube

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry kimagereadersecret --docker-server ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io --docker-email coreyp@united-systems.com --docker-username=kimage-reader --docker-password 4b37b896-a04e-48b4-a950-5f1abdd3e7aa
```

-- `kubectl.exe describe pod simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-2hg2m`

```
Name:               simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-2hg2m
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               aks-agentpool-97052351-0/10.240.0.4
Start Time:         Mon, 17 Jun 2019 15:22:30 -0500
Labels:             app=simpledotnetapi-pod
                    pod-template-hash=6fbf97df55
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 10.240.0.26
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55
Containers:
  simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi:
    Container ID:
    Image:          ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi
    Image ID:
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-hj9b5 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-hj9b5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-hj9b5
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m                 default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned default/simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-2hg2m to aks-agentpool-97052351-0
  Normal   BackOff    4m (x6 over 5m)    kubelet, aks-agentpool-97052351-0  Back-off pulling image "ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi"
  Normal   Pulling    4m (x4 over 5m)    kubelet, aks-agentpool-97052351-0  pulling image "ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi"
  Warning  Failed     4m (x4 over 5m)    kubelet, aks-agentpool-97052351-0  Failed to pull image "ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required]
  Warning  Failed     4m (x4 over 5m)    kubelet, aks-agentpool-97052351-0  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     24s (x22 over 5m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-97052351-0  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

-- `kubectl.exe get pod simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-2hg2m -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-06-17T20:22:30Z
  generateName: simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-
  labels:
    app: simpledotnetapi-pod
    pod-template-hash: 6fbf97df55
  name: simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-2hg2m
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55
    uid: a99e4ac8-8ec3-11e9-9bf8-86d46846735e
  resourceVersion: "813190"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/simpledotnetapi-deployment-6fbf97df55-2hg2m
  uid: a1c220a2-913d-11e9-801a-c6aef815c06a
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-hj9b5
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: kimagereadersecret
  nodeName: aks-agentpool-97052351-0
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-hj9b5
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-hj9b5
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-06-17T20:22:30Z
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-06-17T20:22:30Z
    message: 'containers with unready status: [simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-06-17T20:22:30Z
    message: 'containers with unready status: [simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-06-17T20:22:30Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - image: ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      waiting:
        message: Back-off pulling image "ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi"
        reason: ImagePullBackOff
  hostIP: 10.240.0.4
  phase: Pending
  podIP: 10.240.0.26
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: 2019-06-17T20:22:30Z
```

-- yaml configuration file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: simpledotnetapi-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: simpledotnetapi-pod
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: simpledotnetapi-pod
        spec:
            imagePullSecrets:
              - name: kimagereadersecret
            containers:
              - name: simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi
                image: ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi
                ports:
                  - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: simpledotnetapi-service
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 80
    selector:
       app: simpledotnetapi
       type: front-end
```

-- output of kubectl get secret kimagereadersecret

```
NAME                 TYPE                             DATA      AGE
kimagereadersecret   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1         1h
```

-- credentials/secret from Kube dashboard

```
{
  "kind": "Secret",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kimagereadersecret",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/kimagereadersecret",
    "uid": "86006aff-9156-11e9-801a-c6aef815c06a",
    "resourceVersion": "830006",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-06-17T23:20:41Z"
  },
  "data": {
    ".dockerconfigjson": "eyJhdXRocyI6eyJ1c3NtaWNyb3NlcnZpY2VyZWdpc3RyeS5henVyZWNyLmlvIjp7InVzZXJuYW1lIjoiMzNjYjBjZTQtOTVmMC00NGJkLWJiYmYtNTZkNTA2ZmY0ZWIzIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiI0YjM3Yjg5Ni1hMDRlLTQ4YjQtYTk1MC01ZjFhYmRkM2U3YWEiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNvcmV5cEB1bml0ZWQtc3lzdGVtcy5jb20iLCJhdXRoIjoiTXpOallqQmpaVFF0T1RWbU1DMDBOR0prTFdKaVltWXROVFprTlRBMlptWTBaV0l6T2pSaU16ZGlPRGsyTFdFd05HVXRORGhpTkMxaE9UVXdMVFZtTVdGaVpHUXpaVGRoWVE9PSJ9fX0="
  },
  "type": "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
}
```

-- Full dump from the Kube Dashboard

```
Failed to pull image "ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/v2/simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required]
```

The entire project is in GitHub @ https://github.com/coreyperkins/KubeSimpleDotNetApi

-- ACR screenshot
[image]

-- Pod Failure in Kube
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain you didn't give it enough permissions:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac 
  --scopes /subscriptions/11870e73-bdb2-47b0-bf27-25d24c41ae24/resourcegroups/USS-MicroService-Test/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/UssMicroServiceRegistry
  --role Reader 
  --name kimage-reader
```

role should be `acrpull`, not reader. and just delete this secret: `kimagereadersecret 1 and reference to it in the pod. kubernetes will handle that for you.

Comment: I added acrpull to kimage-reader, but I am still seeing the same results.

Comment: you dont need that secret, remove it from the pod\deployment definition

Comment: no, you dont. with ACR AKS can do that "magically" behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be missing the `kimagereadersecret` in your Kubernetes cluster. As I understand `az ad sp create-for-rbac` just creates access to Azure resources, but how does k8s know which credentials to use to pull from the registry? You can follow [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) to create the registry secret. You can check that it exists with:

```
$ kubectl get secret kimagereadersecret
```

In your case, it could be that it's defaulting to no credentials or using whatever you have configured for Docker which doesn't have access to `ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi`

Comment: Thanks for the response Rico. See my last edit, I put in the output for kubectl get secret kimagereadersecret. It also shows up in the Kube dashboard.

Comment: Also, I can do a docker login with the credentials in the secret successfully. It's leading me to think I have a mistake in my yaml, but I am not sure what, it looks good to me.

Comment: Did you base64 your docker credentials as the kubernetes doc page says?

Comment: Yep, I attached the output from the dashboard just now.

Comment: I put the project up on GitHub (https://github.com/coreyperkins/KubeSimpleDotNetApi) if you'd like to take a look. :) Just keep in mind the aks.yaml is the only file I am currently using. The other yaml files aren't used.

Comment: Did you follow this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks

Comment: I did not, I followed this one (https://thorsten-hans.com/how-to-use-private-azure-container-registry-with-kubernetes). But I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, try the official one. Things might have changed, the link you provided is from 2017

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, maybe it's just a mistake that you make. All the things you have done is OK. Just in the deployment, you need to change the image with a tag like below:

```
image: ussmicroserviceregistry.azurecr.io/simpledotnetapi-simpledotnetapi:tag
```

Set the tag the same as you set in the ACR. Then it will work well. If you do not set tag, then it will use the default tag `latest` and it probably is not right.

Comment: Right now I am only using latest.

Comment: @coreyperkins Are you sure the tag of the image that you use in the ACR is latest?

Comment: yes, I am positive latest, it is my own tag currently

Comment: @coreyperkins Do you take a try? And the same error? Can you show the screenshot of the image in the ACR?

Comment: screenshots added. Thanks!

Comment: @coreyperkins You use a wrong image name. It should be an underline in the image name. So the image name is `simpledotnetapi_simpledotnetapi:latest`.

Comment: I had already made that fix, just hadn't posted it. Still stuck with the same results.

Comment: @coreyperkins So surprised, I find you create the kubernetes secret with the service principal name? This is a wrong value, you need to use the service principal application Id, that's the real value that you need to use.

Comment: I had no luck, finally decided to go with my open docker hub account while testing and I'll swing back to this one later. I did try using the service principal id as well but it also did not work.

Comment: @coreyperkins There must some step you did in a wrong way.